# Why is the program taking so much time even after threading?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have been trying to look up for active hosts connected to a gateway with specific masks, but it is taking a lot of time even after threading. Also the total host are not showing correct.

CODE is:

```
import subprocess, sys, threading, time, queue

t = 0
[a,b,c,d] = list(sys.argv[1].split("."))
mask = int(sys.argv[2])
p = queue.Queue()

def alive(host):
    reply = str(subprocess.Popen(["ping", "-n","1","-w","5",host],
                          stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0])

    if "TTL=" in reply :
        if host != sys.argv[1]:
            print(host," is UP")
            p.put(1)
        else:
            p.put(0)
    else:
        p.put(0)

start_time = time.time()

if mask == 8:
    for i in range(1,256):
        for j in range(1,256):
            for k in range(1,256):
                iplist = [a,str(i),str(j),str(k)]
                ip = '.'.join(iplist)
                thread = threading.Thread(target = alive(ip))
                thread.start()

elif mask == 16:
    for i in range(1,256):
        for j in range(1,256):
                iplist = [a,b,str(i),str(j)]
                ip = '.'.join(iplist)
                thread = threading.Thread(target = alive(ip))
                thread.start()

elif mask == 24:
    for i in range(1,256):
        iplist = [a,b,c,str(i)]
        ip = '.'.join(iplist)
        thread = threading.Thread(target = alive(ip))
        thread.start()

else:
    print("Mask must be 8 , 16 or 24")

for i in range(p.qsize()):
    if p.get == 1:
        t+=1
    else:
        pass

print("\nTotal no. of hosts connected to ",sys.argv[1], " is ",t)
print("Total time taken is ",time.time() - start_time)
```

COMMAND LINE INPUT:

```
python uphost.py 192.168.1.1 24
```

OUTPUT:

```
192.168.1.20  is UP
192.168.1.30  is UP

Total no. of hosts connected to  192.168.1.1  is  0
Total time taken is  125.90091395378113
```

Comment: You are creating 256 threads... what kind of supercomputer you have? :)

Comment: If I recall, Python's multithreading isn't true multithreading because of GIL limitations. Can anyone confirm or deny this?

Comment: @erip it does not use multiple CPUs, for that we need to use multiprocessing. But in this example the threads are not CPU-intensive, mainly used due to blocking (the 5 second timeout in the ping command), so single-CPU multithreading is still useful

Answer (score 2):

You are creating way over too many threads (256, 256^2, 256^3). And thread creation has an overhead which you need to balance with the amount of work each thread is doing.

I think a better solution is to use a Thread pool (see https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) with a predetermined number (as many as the number of threads your machine supports).

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the mentioned issue with using too many threads, your actual problem (for the 125 seconds) is that you're not using threading for the ping command because of this

```
elif mask == 24:
    for i in range(1, 256):
        iplist = [a, b, c, str(i)]
        ip = '.'.join(iplist)
        thread = threading.Thread(target=alive(ip))
        thread.start()
```

You are calling `alive(ip)` in your main thread and the return of that call is the target of the spawned thread..

What you want to do is

```
elif mask == 24:
    for i in range(1, 256):
        iplist = [a, b, c, str(i)]
        ip = '.'.join(iplist)
        thread = threading.Thread(target=alive, args=[ip])
        thread.start()
```

This is the first issue with your code (not threaded).

Once you fix it, you find another issue. You're not waiting for the threads to complete, so:

```
...
threads = []
...
elif mask == 24:
    for i in range(1, 25):
        iplist = [a, b, c, str(i)]
        ip = '.'.join(iplist)
        thread = threading.Thread(target=alive, args=[ip])
        threads.append(thread)
        thread.start()

...

for thread in threads:
    thread.join()

for i in range(p.qsize()):
    if p.get() == 1:
        t += 1
    else:
        pass
```

And the added typo-fix here was the `p.get` (without `()`).

But you should look into `multiprocessing.Pool` like simpel01 mentioned as it is simpler, cleaner to use and manages a pool of threads instead of going into a spawn-frenzy mode :)

EDIT > updated code with multiprocessing.Pool

```
import subprocess
import sys
import multiprocessing
import time

[a, b, c, d] = list(sys.argv[1].split("."))
mask = int(sys.argv[2])


def alive(host):
    reply = str(
        subprocess.Popen(
            ["ping", "-c", "1", "-t", "5", host],  # edited for linux
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE
        ).communicate()[0]
    )

    if "ttl=" in reply:
        if host != sys.argv[1]:
            print(host, " is UP")
            return host

    return None


def main():
    ips = []
    if mask == 8:
        for i in range(1, 256):
            for j in range(1, 256):
                for k in range(1, 256):
                    iplist = [a, str(i), str(j), str(k)]
                    ips.append('.'.join(iplist))
    elif mask == 16:
        for i in range(1, 256):
            for j in range(1, 256):
                    iplist = [a, b, str(i), str(j)]
                    ips.append('.'.join(iplist))
    elif mask == 24:
        for i in range(1, 256):
            iplist = [a, b, c, str(i)]
            ips.append('.'.join(iplist))
    else:
        print("Mask must be 8 , 16 or 24")
        return

    start_time = time.time()
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=100)
    hosts_up = [x for x in pool.map(alive, ips) if x]

    print("\nTotal no. of hosts connected to ", sys.argv[1], " is ", len(hosts_up))
    print("Total time taken is ", time.time() - start_time)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Result

```
$ python3 uphosts.py 192.168.1.1 24
192.168.1.66  is UP
192.168.1.65  is UP
192.168.1.254  is UP

Total no. of hosts connected to  192.168.1.1  is  3
Total time taken is  15.280648946762085
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help... It is fixed now :)
Sorry for my bad programming, I am just a naive in programming :'(

Comment: By clicking the checkmark next to the answer (just noticed you're a new user and could probably use the explanation :))